# Spring i18n does not work

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, internationalization

I am getting `javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'welcome.message' for locale 'en_US'` error, when I use  tag.

my configuration is in /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml and looks like this

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages"/>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>

<bean id="cookieResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
    <property name="cookieName" value="my-locale-cookie"/>
    <property name="cookieMaxAge" value="3600"/>
</bean>

<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang"/>
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

my messages are in `src/main/resources/messages.properties and messages_en_US.properties and messages_fr.properties.`

Comment: Did you confirmed that you have an entry in your `messages_en_US.properties` file with key `welcome.message`?

Comment: @VPK welcome.message=blalbalbb is the content of my messages_en_US.properties

Comment: Is there any message mapping in `messages.properties` file with the same key? Or try changing the file name `messages_en_US.properties` to `messages_en.properties`.

Comment: Yes there is and I tried with same error. It seems that spring cannot find these messages or cannot load the properties from them.

Comment: Have you tried changing the file name as specified in my prev comment? One more thing you can try, add another message only in `messages_en.properties` file, use it just for testing and do not forget to rebuild your project.

Comment: Yes i tried, it does not help. I am getting 
WARNING: ResourceBundle [messages] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name messages, locale en_US error in tomcat console. The error should be here  <property name="basename" value="resources.messages"/> in value part or it is some nasty bug.

Comment: @VPK Could this cause an issue?  <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />

Comment: Yes, I think so. Try to replace it with `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />` as all your resources would be searched in that folder. With this, I guess you don't have your message resources in `/WEB-INF/resources` folder.

Comment: It does not work. I tried it both ways. The values messages is red in idea, but I have no idea what to put there so the framework recognized it.